# How can i force software to use the correct GPU?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, gpu, 3d

i have a laptop with 2 GPUs
intel and NVIDIA GTX . i use 3d software obviuosly i would like to use the powerful one which is nvidia ,
however it keep using intel hd graphics
and i already selected NVIDIA Performance mode in nvidia settings
how can i change this sofwtare to be using nvidia gpu
thanks in advance